# HTML how to use different fonts

Tags: html, fonts

if i place my `ttf` font file in my websites root folder lets say named `AMC.tff` and in my website use `<font face="AMC">` is it going to work... if not than what is the method to use unusual fonts in your website

Comment: **Don't use `<font>`.** You may have confused HTML's `<font face="">` with CSS's `@font-face`.

Comment: Making sites with "unusual fonts" is normally a bad idea. Apart from the fact that all clients need to download/install the font in order to see the page as you meant, you need to be sure that you have the legal right to redistribute the font.

Comment: i have legal right cuz i make the fonts myself... i want isn't there a way in which these fonts could be used without being installed on the clients machine... like place them in root folder or something because the font files are not installed they are just copied in a folder `c:\windows\fonts`.. font files are like dll no matter directly referenced or picked through a list that an os might be managing or from some folder... its just availability and a link to a file that matters...

Comment: i mean the website where you can get fonts... they provide preview on custom text.. how they do it... and it IS actually text that they give a preview of... not a series of combined images of alphabets of those fonts...

Comment: See codescape's answer. Also Web fonts are **not** copied to `C:\Windows\Fonts` or `/usr/share/fonts`.

Comment: @Junaid font doesnt get copied to Fonts folder as you are assuming, if you are targeting CSS3 supportive browsers use @font-face, (not sure bt Chrome doesnt support the tag), check the answers for other alternatives

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can include True Type Fonts with the help of the CSS 3 property `@font-face`. The following CSS would apply your AMC font to all `<h1/>` tags:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "AMC";
  src: url("./AMC.ttf") format("truetype");
}
h1 {
  font-family: "AMC", sans-serif;
}
```

For browsers that have no support for webfonts you should specify a similar alternative to your font. In the above example `sans-serif` would be used if AMC cannot be found because the `@font-face` tag was not recognized by the browser.

Comment: A great article to this topic can be found here: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/cssatten

Comment: Nice example, great article, I might try this myself

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use Custom Font for your site, you can give a go for Cufon

> http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/

Detailed Tutorial for using CUfon on your site

> http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/the-easiest-way-to-use-any-font-you-wish/

Forgot to add, You can also use CSS3 property

> @font-face

Supported by FF3.5 and above, Opera 10 and above, IE 7,8(not sure about 6)

Answer (score 0):

No, the fonts in a browser is based on fonts installed on the visitor's machine.

I don't know much about this area, so I can't tell you which one of these works or is considered best practices, but check out:

- [SiFr](http://www.mikeindustries.com/blog/sifr-)
- [typeface.js](http://css-tricks.com/typefacejs-a-sifr-alternative/)
- [Cufon](http://aaronwinborn.com/blogs/aaron/cuf%C3%B3n-alternative-sifr-image-replacement)

Answer (score 0):

No. Apart from the fact that `<font>`is deprecated, you have to use the CSS3 [`@font-face`](http://www.css3.info/preview/web-fonts-with-font-face/) directive, or older more compatible methods such as [Cufon](http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/) and [Sifr](http://www.mikeindustries.com/blog/sifr).

Answer (score 0):

Check this link out:
[How to get non-standard font with effect in use of web site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797506/how-to-get-non-standard-font-with-effect-in-use-of-web-site/3797667#3797667)

I have explained in detail how to embed fonts in a webpage and make it browser compatible. 
Font embedding is also a risky affair, as the font license sometimes doesn't allow.

PS - And please make sure that you don't repeat questions in stackoverflow as this question has been answered many times.